# What is the proper way to list localhost as a referrer for an embedded map?

Tags: google-maps, localhost, referrer

What is the proper way to list localhost as a referrer under API/Credentials for an embedded map? I have tried "localhost", the name of the site in my MAMP set up, and my IP address but none of those work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [127.0.0.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)

> On most computer systems, "localhost" resolves to the IP address
>   127.0.0.1, which is the most commonly used IPv4 loopback address, and to the IPv6 loopback address ::1.

Or try http://localhost:8080

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have tried 127.0.0.1, and http://localhost:8080, http://localhost:8888, and ::1. None of these have done the trick. Other suggestions? Do you need more information? I am working on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://localhost/* on a PC.  You don't have to use the port number. If you leave it off you can use it on any.